# How do I fix "Member is ambiguous" error?

Tags: c++, c++98

I use Borland C++ 4.5 as my school recommends it.
When I try to run this code, I get three errors when I try to run the code.
I try to change the access specifier every time, but I fail.

```
#include "iomanip.h"
#include "iostream.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class person
{
public:
    int code;
    char name[50];
    void PEnter()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Code :\n";
        cin >> code;
        cout << "\nEnter Name :\n";
        gets(name);
    }
};

class account : public person
{
public:
    float pay;
    void AcEnter()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Pay :\n";
        cin >> pay;
    }
};

class admin : public person
{
public:
    int experience;
    void AdEnter()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Experience :\n";
        cin >> experience;
    }
};

class master : public account, admin
{
public:
    void MEnter()
    {
        PEnter();
        AcEnter();
        AdEnter();
    }
    void MRet()
    {
        cout << setw(20) << name << "\t" << setw(7) << code << "\t"
             << setw(6) << pay << "\t" << setw(3) << experience << "\n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    master M[200];
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    do {
        M[i].MEnter();
        ++i;
        cout << "\nEnter More :\n";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');
    int j = i;
    clrscr();
    cout << setw(20) << "Name\t" << setw(7) << "Code\t" << setw(6)
         << "Pay\t" << setw(3) << "\tExperience\n";
    for (i = 0; i <= j; ++i) {
        M[i].MRet();
    }
    getch();
}
```

These are the three errors that I get:

```
Error NONAME00.CPP 43 : Member is ambiguous 'person::PEnter' and 'person::PEnter' in function master::MEnter()
Error NONAME00.CPP 49 : Member is ambiguous 'person::name' and 'person::name' in function master::MRet()
Error NONAME00.CPP 49 : Member is ambiguous 'person::code' and 'person::code' in function master::MRet()
```

I do not know whether the class `person` is being inherited or not (by the `master` class).

Comment: *"I use Borland C++ 4.5 as my school recommends it"* Isn't that a **20 year old IDE**?

Comment: @dyp, Yup, almost 20 years on the dot. Why anyone would recommend it when there are IDEs and compilers that are completely 100% free and new and actually standard-conforming is beyond me.

Comment: @user, You've tagged your question C++98. That is incorrect. Your code is not C++98, it is pre-standard C++. For example, `void main` and `#include "iostream.h"`. This class/school is hurting you more than helping you.

Comment: hey , it is true that the IDE is 20 years old . But our school syllabi tells us to follow either Turbo C++ or Borland C++....

Answer (score 4):

You hit the `diamond inheritance` problem. What it is and how to solve it described here [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) Note inheritance in the wiki example is very close to yours so there should not be any problem for you to follow solution provided there

Comment: I'm a complete newbie , and our syllabus does not prescribe virtual functions . Is there any other way to solve this??

Comment: @user3896438 you should read article more carefully, solution is not using virtual functions but virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

One can also inherit the base class as virtual

```
class admin : public virtual person
class account : public virtual person
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation on why this should work.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-base-class-in-c/   This page has excellently explained why we use Virtual inheritence to solve the diamond inheritence problem and avoid ambiguity errors.

Comment: Sorry, I meant adding it on the answer itself (by clicking on "Edit" above). It would be helpful to also add quotes of the most relevant parts of the link directly on the answer (as the link may change/go down in the future).

Answer (score -1):

call the fn as

```
person::PEnter();
```

input the value like this -

```
person::name;
person::code;
```